# Javascript iframe src becomes Null at start only

Tags: javascript, iframe, null, src

I'm having a bit of a problem with my iframe src. I set up a drop-down list which changes the iframe src url and then saves the selection. everything works fine except when you load the webpage for the first time I get a 404 error and iframe src becomes null. i tried manually setting a url and using a script to change the url onload but that broke the saving selection. thanks for your time.

**EDIT**
Thanks to *lorefnon* he pointed me in the right direction I was able to create a fix here is the full working code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>dropdown remember selection test</title>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="stream_iframe" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="854"   height="480" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" name="stream_iframe" src="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/moviebay"></iframe> 

<form>
<select name="options" onchange="callMe(this);" id="selectMovie">
<option value="" disabled selected>SELECT STREAM</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/ninjatart">Nightsanity</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/111aaacharkcomedy">ComedyCentral</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/ducktoaster">JPGameShow</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/lmshows_mws">SurvivalReality</option> 
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/cyberjedi">TV Series</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/anime_hq">Anime HQ</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/animationnation101">Toons</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/frightfest0001">Horror Movies 1</option> 
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/freakyfetish101">Horror Movies 2</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/moviebay">MovieBay</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv//embed/video/111aaacharkmovies">Movies</option> 
</select>
</form>
<script>
function callMe(obj){
localStorage.setItem("selectedStream",obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value);
document.getElementById('stream_iframe').src =       obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
}

var selectedStream = localStorage.getItem("selectedStream");

if (localStorage.getItem("selectedStream") === null) {
  document.getElementById("stream_iframe").src =  "https://streamup.com/acgn_music_box/embeds/video?startMuted=false"; 
} else {
    document.getElementById("stream_iframe").src =   localStorage.getItem("selectedStream");
    document.getElementById("selectMovie").value =  ""+localStorage.getItem("selectedStream")+"";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked your console for any warnings?

Comment: It sounds like `callMe()` is getting called on page load, with the default value of your `<select>` tag being the empty string.  If you can't stop that from happening, can you set the default value to something valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when your code runs for the first time, `localStorage.getItem` returns null which is assigned to the src attribute of your iframe.

You can check for this condition and either do nothing, in which case the existing src in the html will be respected, or you can assign 'about:blank' to show an empty page without 404 error.

```
<script>
function callMe(obj){
localStorage.setItem("selectedStream",obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value);
document.getElementById('stream_iframe').src =   obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
}

var selectedStream = localStorage.getItem("selectedStream");

if (selectedStream) {
  document.getElementById("stream_iframe").src = selectedStream;
  document.getElementById("selectMovie").value = selectedStream;
} else {
  document.getElementById("stream_iframe").src =  "about:blank"; 
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks that breaks the saved selection though.